# Auto layout with Scrollview and sticky view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, sticky

So you I have this ViewController in a storyboard which has a UIScrollView with several views added to it. The selected view (sticky) in the image below, which doesn't have correct constraints, is supposed to stay on top of the scrollview when scrolling. Now the 'description' is a dynamic height text. The selected view should stay at the bottom of the 'description' text but when it has reach the top of the scrollview it will remain at the top.

What's the best approach to use here?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: "the selected view is supposed to stay on top of the scrollview when scrolling" - Does it mean that the selected view should scroll along with scroll view. 
The last line says that the selected view should scroll and stick to the top.

Comment: Make sure your view hierarchy is properly laid out (sticky view above, i.e. sibling not subview)

Comment: Best approach, primarily opinion based questions, are likely to be flagged for deletion. Until then, use one or more layout constraints that you can manipulate at runtime, either by enabling/disabling such constraints, or changing the `constant` value.